# Is there a way to change all the page link url according to browser url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, url-rewriting

any how i have manage to create dynamic subdomain and my url like
[http://go.stackoverflow.com/]

but all the links of the page are remain
[https://stackoverflow.com/]

but i want to change all the links of my page on load to

[http://go.stackoverflow.com/]

any javascript, jquery or php ?

thank you.

Comment: you can set the browser url to the other links by setting the value from 'location.href'. It will give you the URL of current page.

Answer (score 3):

Use only /path-to-page in html. Not hardcoded path like http://domain.com/path-to-page